# Probability getting $2$ correct from $3$ trials?

Tags: probability

could someone explain the math for this?

You have a puzzle with $9$ pieces. You already have $7$ pieces, and two is missing. You have three trials to get those missing two pieces. Every time you pick up a piece from a bag, the probability of getting any of the nine pieces is always the same ($\frac19=0.11$). Picking up a piece doesn't affect the number of pieces in a bag, so you end up having those two missing pieces or you can pick up the same piece multiple times or any other combination.

what I understand it is that you have several ways to get pieces (three trials), c = correct and i = incorrect.

iii
iic
ici
cii
icc
cci
cic
ccc

So, how do you calculate the propability that both are correct pieces?

Answer (score 0):

This probability tree might be useful. (Or it might be too small to see.)

[image]On your first draw, there are 2 correct pieces in the bag, so the chance of pulling one of them out is 2/9. The chance of pulling neither out is 7/9. If you pull a correct one, you will be at node c?? on the tree. Otherwise, you will be at node i??.

If you are at node c??, there will be only 1 correct piece in the bag, so the chance of drawing it is 1/9. If you succeed, you will be at node cc?, if not, then you'll be at ci?. From cc?, no further draws are needed. The probability of reaching node cc? is 2/9 x 1/9 = 2/81.

The probabilities of reaching the other nodes with 2 correct choices are 16/729 and 28/729, as shown on the tree. The chance of picking 2 correct pieces is, therefore, 2/81 + 16/729  + 14/729 = 48/729.

Comment: Probabilities from ic? should be 1/9 to icc and 8/9 to ici (instead of 2/9 and 7/9). Which then gives 2/18 + 16/729 + 14/729 = 48/729.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the text and picture.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion (PIE).

Suppose the missing pieces are pieces number $1$ and $2$, and let's say $X_i$ is the event that the sequence of three draws is missing piece $i$, for $i=1,2$. Then the probability that neither piece $1$ nor piece $2$ is missing is
$$\begin{align}
P((X_1 \cup X_2)^c) &= 1 - P(X_1) - P(X_2) + P(X_1 \cap X_2) \\
&= 1 -  \left( \frac{8}{9} \right)^3 -  \left( \frac{8}{9} \right)^3 + \left( \frac{7}{9} \right)^3 \\
&= \frac{48}{729}
\end{align}$$